# Trazer todos registros caso parâmetro seja diferente

Tags: sql, query

Tenho uma tabela `contrato` com o campo `concluido` do tipo `tinyint(1)`, se for 0 ele não está concluído e se for 1 ele está concluído. Vou passar esse valor por parâmetro para a query, como faço para trazer todos os dados quando o valor desse parâmetro for diferente de 0 e 1?

Comment: Qual o Banco de dados que está usando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize a cláusula `OR` para busca condicional.

```
SELECT c.*
  FROM contrato c
 WHERE :parametro NOT IN (0, 1)
    OR c.concluido = :parametro;
```

---

Caso o parâmetro possa estar nulo, utilize mais uma cláusula `OR`:

```
SELECT c.*
  FROM contrato c
 WHERE :parametro IS NULL
    OR :parametro NOT IN (0, 1)
    OR c.concluido = :parametro;
```

Comment: Não seria `NOT IN (0,1)`?

Comment: @Willian verdade, vou corrigir

Comment: Sim, (0,1), deu certinho. Obrigado.

Comment: E como faço para trazer tudo quando o parâmetro for null? Exemplo: `/contratos`

Comment: @FernandoZabin adicionei na resposta

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o "coalesce" (padrão em todos os bancos sql) para economizar um "or" no caso do seu parametro vir nulo também.

SELECT *
FROM Contrato
WHERE 
 concluido = :parametro
 or 
 coalesce(:parametro,-1) not in (0, 1);

Uma outra forma seria essa:

SELECT *
FROM Contrato
WHERE 
 concluido = case when coalesce(:parametro,-1) between 0 and 1 then :parametro else concluido end